# Convert PDF to HTML (Code)

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-to-html

Is there any way to convert a pdf file to HTML code? I founded tools for convert PDF in HTML but all convert PDF in image and insert it into html page. I need to convert PDF in html code for generate dinamic pages.

Comment: are you searching only free tools?

Comment: No i dont. Im looking for any idea to do it.

Comment: I need to inverse, PDF to HTML code.

Comment: Google comes with [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/).

Comment: @colymore PDF.js basically converts PDF to HTML to show it in your browser ...

Comment: @Sirko Yes i know but i need to convert a PDF (Its a bill) for get a similar html with divs to make it later dinamically.

Comment: @colymore And how is this different?

Comment: pdf.js uses canvas api to import the pdf like a image inside a html, i cant edit it.

Comment: @colymore If I open some PDFs with it, most of the stuff generated is `<div>` nodes. Is your source PDF really a text one or more like a picture? In the latter case, you'll need some OCR library.

Comment: You are rigth, i dont know my pdfs its images..Its possible to convert it to text pdf and convert it to html?

Comment: @colymore

Did u find solution?